# Error VS 2015 CTP 6 + Cordova + Windows 10 Technical Preview for Phones

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I am able to create and run a Blank App (Cordova Cordova) on windows 10 phone technical preview.  The app is installed on the phone, appears in the app list and runs.  However, I get the following error in Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6

`Severity Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       ERROR: Error code -2146233087 for command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\Xap Deployment\XapDeployCmd.exe with args: /installlaunch,D:/erase/BlankCordovaApp2/BlankCordovaApp2/bld/Debug/platforms/wp8/Bin/debug/CordovaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap,/targetdevice:0`

[image]

Comment: Report beta bugs to connect.microsoft.com.  Be sure to attach your project, the SystemException it fails with isn't going to help them diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround to this might be to unplug the phone from your machine, plug it back in, and try the WP8 deploy again without doing an 8.1 or 10 deployment.

If it doesn't help, can you look at your detailed build for any build failures messages? You can turn on the detailed output from Tools --> Options --> Project and Solutions --> Build and Run settings.

Comment: Subhag Oak,  Thanks for the workaround.  Unfortunately, it did not work.  I do set the "Build and Run" verbosity settings to Diagnostic and it does help, but in this case I just get the following      inline `2>ERROR: Error code -2146233087 for command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\Xap Deployment\XapDeployCmd.exe with args: /installlaunch,D:/erase/BlankCordovaApp2/bld/Debug/platforms/wp8/Bin/debug/CordovaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap,/targetdevice:0
=== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ===
=== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ===`

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I had NPM and Gulp files in my Blank Cordova app.  I created a new Blank Cordova app and no errors appear when I build the app in VS.

There seems to be a problem with the node-modules folder. I am able to prevent the error from occurring by removing just the node_modules folder that's created by Gulp or Grunt file in the Visual Studio Project. [image]

The output build message provides some detail(see below). Fortunately, the error is now gone, but that doesn't solve my new problem with the node_modules folder.

```js
2>  Deploying package to Device
2>  Done.
2>ERROR: Error code -2146233087 for command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\Xap Deployment\XapDeployCmd.exe with args: /installlaunch,D:/erase/BlankCordovaApp2/bld/Debug/platforms/wp8/Bin/debug/CordovaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap,/targetdevice:0
2>  Command finished with error code 2: D:\erase\BlankCordovaApp2\bld\Debug\platforms\wp8\cordova\run.bat --nobuild,--target=Device,--debug
2>  
2>ERROR: Error code -2146233087 for command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\Xap Deployment\XapDeployCmd.exe with args: /installlaunch,D:/erase/BlankCordovaApp2/bld/Debug/platforms/wp8/Bin/debug/CordovaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap,/targetdevice:0
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```